# Is would necessary in "... when I got paid I would leave my office..."?

Tags: will-would

> Every month when I got paid I would leave my office and go to the bookshop and spend a little fortune.

"Would" is here to indicate that the action was done many times. I was wondering if "would" was necessary since "every month" was written in the beginning of the sentence and make us understand that the author went at least  more than one time. Maybe every month is only related to the salary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Every month when I got paid I would leave my office and go to the bookshop and spend a little fortune.** is would necessary?

First lets introduce some Good English as opposed to Grammatically correct English.

In this sentence No it is not necessary to use would as it is not possible. There is no such thing as a little fortune. By definition a fortune is a large amount, although there is an idiom that uses small fortune. Also the sentence is an "And" too many. So with minor alterations the sentence becomes

Every month when I got paid I would leave my office, go to the bookshop and spend a **small fortune**.

It could also be written **without the would** with some small changes.

Every month when I got paid I left my office, went to the bookshop and spent a small fortune.

The meaning without "**would** " is slightly different though. Here **would** is not used as an emphasis. Why would is used, is to mean, **"most months"** as opposed to  every month. In the revised sentence without would it means it did happen every month. It is a positive statement "I went"

**Note** "**every month** "was written in the beginning of the sentence. However this relates to every month he gets paid. Would relates to leaving the office for the book store.

> **would** modal verb (FREQUENCY) used to talk about things in the past that happened often or always: [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would)

Answer (score 0):

"Every month when I got paid I would leave my office and go to the bookshop and spend a little fortune."

"Every month when I got paid I left my office and went to the bookshop and spent a little fortune."

Both of these are correct and their difference is subtle. I think you're right, however, that the "would" emphasizes the habitual nature of the practice.